# Open source implementation of Multiscale Combinatorial Grouping

Tags: algorithms, python, image-processing, computer-vision

I would like to use [Multiscale Combinatorial Grouping](https://www2.eecs.berkeley.edu/Research/Projects/CS/vision/grouping/mcg/) for my PhD research. However, I am restricted to use open-source implementations and this one runs on Matlab.

Does anyone know of an equivalent **contour detection method** that works on large images that is implemented **open-source**, preferably in Python?

Here some more background info. Equivalent methods would be:

- [Contour detection and hierarchical image segmentation](https://www2.eecs.berkeley.edu/Research/Projects/CS/vision/grouping/resources.html) -> cannot handle images of more than 1000x1000 pixels and runs on Matlab
- [SLIC Superpixels](https://ivrl.epfl.ch/research/superpixels) -> creates too many redundant segments

I am interested in detecting contours of visible objects in drone imagery with a resolution of 2-5cm per pixel and extents of up to 1kmx1km for the purpose of automating cadastral mapping. Here an example of what the contour detection output should look like:

[image]

Comment: Did you try using Octave instead of Matlab? It usually can run most of the Matlab codes without the need to do the changes.

Comment: No, not yet. I will have a look.

Comment: Does this help you? https://github.com/sxdxedu/ContourGAN

Comment: @AntonMenshov: I unsuccessfully tried running the code in Octave, since it uses some toolbox packages that are in Matlab only

Comment: @David: The network-based approach you suggested seems too complex for my purpose right now: the network probably requires adjustments to remotely sensed data and thus a throughout understanding of the approach.

Comment: hmm, you might try to look for the missing pieces (like analogs of those toolboxes) in Octave/Python etc. If those are popular toolboxes, you have a chance to find an alternative and work only on the interfaces between them rather than a full-blown new development.